# Specify Required field from UI and fetch ONLY these fields from Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

i use MVC 4,EF 5 code first,my service layer only interact with domain classes (POCO) and my UI layer interact with ViewModel classes (POCO).

My Question:

How i can specify Required field from UI and fetch ONLY these fields from Database in service layer?

Answer (score 1):

Building a `Select` expression dynamically is not easy because the type (named or anonymous) in which to capture the result is not know at compile time. I've seen some efforts here at StackOverflow, but they were fruitless if I remember correctly (I'can't find them at the moment).

What you can do is use [Entity Sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx) to build a query string.

```
var queryString = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM MyTable"
                               , string.Join(",",fieldsFromUi); // WHERE...?
var q = new ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord>(queryString , context);
```

where `context` is an `ObjectContext` instance. [`DbDataRecord`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatarecord%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is a dictionary-like structure from which you can pick the values to display.

Comment: @user197508 Does this make sense or didn't I understand your question well?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/top-10-asp.net-mvc-best-practices.htm) is bet practice for MVC.
better is use viewmodel
You can user viewmodel and requird list.for example this is view model and u should pass this model to view

```
public class LoginPageVM
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Are you really trying to login without entering username?")]
    [DisplayName("Username/e-mail")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter password:)")]
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Stay logged in when browser is closed")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

in view

```
@model CamelTrap.Models.ViewModels.LoginPageVM

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m);
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="submit" />
}
```

and in controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LoginPage()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoginPage(LoginPageVM model)
{
    ...code to login user to application...
    return View(model);
}
```

[image]